# How to use custom DateTime format

Tags: asp.net, datetime, string-formatting

The problem is that a specifier `d` represents at the same time a "Short date pattern" in Standard DateTime Format Strings and "the day of the month as a number from 1 through 31" in Custom DateTime Format Strings. The latter is what I actually need.

But if I use something like

```
String.Format("{0:d}", dt);
```

I get a ShortDate (e.g. "3/9/2008").

So how should I use `d` in order to get just the day of the month (e.g. "3")?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that this is the easiest solution:

```
dateTime.Day.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.Now.ToString("%d");

Or "dd" if you like leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Put a `%` before the d, ie

```
String.Format("{0:%d}", dt);
```

... but I would write

```
dt.ToString("%d");
```

(See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers), I think you just needed to scroll down a bit more)

Answer (score 1):

dt.Day gives day (of course if dt is Datetime)

check msdn [DateTime.Day](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
String.Foramt("{0}", dt.ToString("dd").TrimStart('0'));
```

I test it. It works.

-- Edit --

Although there are better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good resource for custom datetime string patterns:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx